# Php laravel 6.0 is it possible to breakdown SQL data and insert into different rows?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just came upon this concept of mine and was wondering if it's do-able.

```
+----+--------+---------+
| ID | chairs | players |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      5 |       5 |
|  2 |      5 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

So for example, there's an input which allows the players to key in the number of participants. For example, if the user inputs '6', and since the maximum number of chairs is '5' per row, the additional user is automatically inputted into the 2nd row. If this is possible, please enlighten me on how to achieve this.

Comment: You can use a stored procedure, where you get all rows and loop through every row. check if the number is bigger and the upddate the row and save the "rest" for the next row, at the end you return the table, i woulod also wriute a function that check if "tbale 1 has a sat free for a friend  In the online world, you would also try to match the persons and in the real world you concept wouldn't work at all or you are really trendy

Comment: How would you go about inserting players, just in another table or?

Comment: I was thinking if it was do-able in the same table, I knew by creating another table, and having a relationship between the tables, it was achievable, but this thought just flew through my mind and I wanted to have an answer to it. Would try to implement what nbk stated above and see if I can get around it.